# Returning handles of elements using QPainter

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing a GUI based on `PyQt5`, and I am wondering if I can get the handles of individual elements that have been created using the `QPainter` class.

I mean, supose that we have three rectangles that have been painted using that class with the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush
import sys

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):      

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Colours')
        self.show()


    def paintEvent(self, e):

        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawRectangles(qp)
        qp.end()


    def drawRectangles(self, qp):

        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(255, 80, 0, 160))
        qp.drawRect(130, 15, 90, 60)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(25, 0, 90, 200))
        qp.drawRect(250, 15, 90, 60)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

**I want to retrieve a kind of handle of each rectangle, for instance, `handle_1`, `handle_2` and `handle_3`, in order to modify the properties of one of them in another thread without plotting the rest of them.**

```
handle_3.setColor(...)
```

If this is not possible, I was wondering if I could create a kind of transparent containter with Qt (which effectively has a handle to modify the stylesheet) and put a `QLabel` inside it. If so, **what container would be the best choice?**

Comment: What do you mean with: *another thread*?

Comment: The paint-event never creates any elements, so what you are asking for makes no sense. But anyway, all you need to do is send the required colours from the thread (using a custom signal), and then repaint using those new colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ekumoro says, the paint-event does not create new elements, so updating one of the rectangles without re-painting the rest of them is impossible.

The only way to achieve this is using containers. Attending to the second question, **I found that the best one is the `QFrame`**.

Comment: I'm developing a GUI that should have precise timings in each stage, and that timings must have millisecond precision. I tried to re-paint all, but it's more time consuming in my case, and it adds time displacements.